# Sending email with php and Outolook 2010 not working

Tags: php

I kindly ask you help in order to fix it.
From windows 7 I am trying to send email using Outlook 2010 with Xampp control panel version 3.2.2.

Php.ini:

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

I also checked my registry for `EnableDCOM`, it is set to 'Y'

My php code is:

```
if (!defined("olMailItem")) {define("olMailItem",0);}
$outlook_Obj = new COM("outlook.application") or die("Outlook no start");

//just to check you are connected.
echo "Loaded MS Outlook, version {$outlook_Obj->Version}\n";
$oMsg = $outlook_Obj->CreateItem(olMailItem);
$oMsg->Recipients->Add($to);
$oMsg->Subject=$subject;
$oMsg->Body=$message;
$oMsg->Save();
$oMsg->Send();
?>
```

Error occur on line `$oMsg->Recipients->Add($to);` is 
Loaded MS Outlook, version 14.0.0.7172

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Error
>   [0x80004004] Operation failed. ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:25 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(25): unknown() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 25

Please help me.

Comment: Can anyone help?Thanks

Comment: why not just use SMTP? Is the server where you deploy this for production really going to have an Outlook client installed? COM interop like this is a very 1990s solution, IMHO.

Comment: necro-moderation